# Need to View Travis CI Test Stats on Repo Pull Requests via the Travis API Calls

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, testing, github-api, travis-ci

I am building a student manager rails app for a class project.I'm already using the Github API to look at an assignments pull requests. As students we fork our instructors assignment, clone it, make our changes, and then we submit pull requests of our completed assignments to turn in our work.

I'm now building an app that integrates all of these steps(and more), and I would like to add in the travis-ci test results to this app. I'm looking at their API, and I can't seem to find how I can show the travis build results for a repos pull requests?

I was wondering if anyone else would know, or could point me in the right direction... here is the link to their API docs... https://api.travis-ci.org/docs/

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've not used the Travis API before, so I'm sorry if I get something wrong. Also, I'm not sure if you're looking just for the status of the Travis build (e.g. success or failure), or the full logs -- so I'll try to cover both.

1. [Fetch the pull request](http://developer.github.com/v3/pulls/#get-a-single-pull-request) via its ID.
2. Extract the `statuses` link from the `_links` hash in the JSON response. This link points to the statuses for the last commit in the pull request, which are used to determine the overall status of the pull request.
3. [Fetch the statuses link](http://developer.github.com/v3/repos/statuses/#list-statuses-for-a-specific-ref). The returned JSON document is an array of status descriptions. Each status has a `status` attribute which describes if the build is `pending`, `success`, `error`, or `failure`. The first status in the array is the latest status and this is what's used for the overall status of the pull request.
4. From the returned JSON body, extract the value of the `target_url` attribute of the first status in the array. For Travis CI builds, the value will be of this format: `https://travis-ci.org/rails/rails/builds/:build_id`.
5. From the extracted `target_url` parse out the ID of the build (`:build_id`).
6. [Fetch the build from Travis](https://api.travis-ci.org/docs/#/builds/%3aid) using the ID you just parsed out.
7. The returned JSON hash will contain an array of build jobs called `matrix`. Iterate over this list of jobs to find the job you want to get logs for. The `id` attribute of each job uniquely identifies a job.
8. [Fetch the job description](https://api.travis-ci.org/docs/#/jobs/%3aid) using the `id` attribute of a job.
9. Extract the `log` attribute from the returned JSON description. This is the raw text log for that job.

Comment: Ivan this worked perfectly thanks so much! To get the raw text log I actually had to do this jobs/:id/log it wasn't excatly what was on the docs for the api...thanks again! :-)